# How to get session data in .js file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

In my application when the user is login the particular `user id` is stored in the session. I want to get this `id` in a `js` file.In this `js` file contain state provider,factory etc

**js**

```
  var sessionValue = "'"+<%=Session["userId"]%>+"'"
  alert(sessionValue)
```

But it is show some error(`Unexpected`)

Comment: You've got `<%=` and other operators outside of string tokens.

Comment: I encourage you to use semi-colons too. They're not necessary but they're good practice.

Comment: you should add the `asp.net` tag

Comment: i done this in php

Comment: ok, then add php tag ;)

Answer (score 1):

1.You can assign session value to hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="<%= Session["userId"] %>">
```

2. Get hidden field value from javascript function.

```
function GetUserId()
{
    var userId = document.getElementById('userId').value;
    alert(userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetUserId()
{

    var userId = '<%= Session["userId"] %>';
    alert(userId);
}
</script>
```

Comment: the alert message is '<%= Session["userId"] %>'

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your `webserver` isn't evaluating as `ASP`  `.js` files. You have three different way to  get what you want

- configure your webserver so that .js files are treated as ASP pages, 
  but noone would ever do that, it would add overhead over your
  code.
- Render your js starting from a .asp page placing in your    html
  something like:  `< script src="mysite/getjavascript.asp" >`
- Load session values with an ajax calls

Remember to print proper headers before printing your `javascript`